# MSBuild error MSB4018 The "SignTask" task failed unexpectedly. In VS2015

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015

when you compile a new project the following error appears:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4018 The "SignTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Acesso negado.

   at Microsoft.DriverKit.Build.Shared.CreateCertificate.CryptAcquireContext(String keyContainerName, String providerName, PROV providerType)
   at Microsoft.DriverKit.Build.Shared.CreateCertificate.CreateSelfSignedCertificate()
   at Microsoft.DriverKit.Build.Tasks.SignTask.AutoGenerateTestCertificate()
   at Microsoft.DriverKit.Build.Tasks.SignTask.AutoPickTestCertificate()
   at Microsoft.DriverKit.Build.Tasks.SignTask.GenerateCommandLineCommands()
   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DriverKit.Build.Tasks.TrackedVCToolTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() BrunoGysinDriver    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\WindowsDriver.common.targets   1348
```

I tried several times but nothing found

Anyone know a solution?

Comment: Does "Acesso negado" mean  access denied? Also Are you initiating build from visual studio or command prompt?

Comment: Run your visual studio in administrator mode.

Comment: @PankajKapare I didn't have to run as admin before on my previous computer. Why do I have to now?

Answer (score 8):

It works! I had the same problem, running on administrator mode works!